# Pass data from bs modal to cloned input fields

Tags: php, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

So i have this issue trying to pass data from bs modal to form inputs, the logic is when i type in first row and press enter a bs modal pops up and show data from database in a table every row has its respective select button so when i click select the chosen row fills up the input fields in the form but after cloning the next rows of inputs and repeat the steps to fill the form from bs modal this only updates all of the fields with same data

[Here is an image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Xuc.png)

here's my code i've been stuck here for days..

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".card").on('keyup', '.live_search', function() {
            var input = $(this).val();
            if (input != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "livesearch.php",
                    data: {
                        input: input
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $(".searchresult").html(data);
                        $(".searchresult").css("display", "block");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $(".searchresult").css("display", "none");
            }
        });

        $(".add-row").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#show-item").prepend(`<tr>
                            <input type="hidden" name="id[]">
                            <td class="col-2">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger delete-row"> <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control live_search" name="material_name[]" placeholder="Nombre Material">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-1">
                                <div class="input-group  input-group-sm ">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="measure_one[]">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class=" col-1">
                                <div class="input-group  input-group-sm ">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="measure_two[]">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class=" col-2">
                                <div class="input-group  input-group-sm ">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="unit_measure[]">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class=" col-1">
                                <div class="input-group  input-group-sm ">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="length[]">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class=" col-1">
                                <div class="input-group  input-group-sm ">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="width[]">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class=" col-1">
                                <div class="input-group  input-group-sm">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price[]">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>`);
        });

        // remove product row
        $('.card').on('click', '.delete-row', function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });

        // modal pops up when pressing enter
        $('.card').on('keyup', '.live_search', function(e) {
            var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {
                // $('.modal').modal('show');
                var product = $(this);
                $('#insert').modal('show', {
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false
                }).on('click', '#selected', function(e) {

                    var id = $(this).attr('data-material-id');
                    var material = $(this).attr('data-material-name');
                    var measure_one = $(this).attr('data-material-measure_one');
                    var measure_two = $(this).attr('data-material-measure_two');

                    var unit_measure = $(this).attr('data-material-unit_measure');
                    var length = $(this).attr('data-material-length');
                    var width = $(this).attr('data-material-width');
                    var price = $(this).attr('data-material-price');

                    $(product).closest('tr').find('[name="supplier_id[]"]').val(id);
                    $(product).closest('tr').find('[name="material_name[]"]').val(material);
                    $(product).closest('tr').find('[name="measure_one[]"]').val(measure_one);
                    $(product).closest('tr').find('[name="measure_two[]"]').val(measure_two);
                    $(product).closest('tr').find('[name="unit_measure[]"]').val(unit_measure);
                    $(product).closest('tr').find('[name="length[]"]').val(length);
                    $(product).closest('tr').find('[name="width[]"]').val(width);
                    $(product).closest('tr').find('[name="price[]"]').val(price);

                    $('#insert').modal('hide');
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { ?>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-sm text-center">
        <thead class="table-primary">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Proveedor</th>
                <th>Material</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) :
                $id = $row['supplier_id'];
                $supplier = $row['supplier'];
                $material = $row['material'];
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $id ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $supplier ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $material ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo '<a href="#" class="btn btn-link" id="selected" datamaterial-id="' . $row['supplier_id'] . '"
                         data-material-name="' . $row['material'] . '" data-material-measure_one="' . $row['measure_one'] . '"
                          data-material-measure_two="' . $row['measure_two'] . '" data-material-unit_measure="' . $row['unit_measure'] . '" 
                          data-material-length="' . $row['length'] . '" data-material-width="' . $row['width'] . '" 
                          data-material-price="' . $row['price']  . '">Select</a>';
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This row in the last keyup eventlistener

```js
var product = $(this);
```

will select every row.

Try this instead:

```js
var product = $(e.target);
```

Read more about event.target [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Comment: it's not working :/

Comment: @Manuel could you elaborate? Is it the same, or blew everything up? Could you debug that line, and post what values you get with `this` and `e.target`

Comment: it happens exactly the same

Comment: please help I'm still stuck with this issue

Comment: @Manuel please provide the debug info I asked for above, thank you.